# Django Foreign Key automatically filled based off of another field on model

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I currently have an "Account" Model and "Account Comments" Model -- keep in mind, that I can't really control the scheme of the database, and I'm writing a wrapper around existing DB.

Under the AccountComments Model, there is a field called "Data". It is where the AccountComments actually are and I'm trying to basically create a foreign key on the Account model without actually having to redesign and add a "AccountComments" field on Account that holds the AccountID.

```
class Account(models.Model):
    AccountID = models.AutoField(editable=False, db_column='AccountID', verbose_name='ID',
                             primary_key=True) 
    acctno = models.IntegerField(editable=True, unique=True, db_column='ACCTNO', verbose_name='Acct #', blank=True,
                             null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    accountComments = models.ForeignKey('accountComments',to_field='accountID',db_column='Data')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.acctno)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Account'


class accountComments(models.Model):
    accountCommentID = models.AutoField(db_column='AccountCommentID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    accountID = models.IntegerField(db_column='AccountID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    EntryUserID = models.IntegerField(db_column='EntryUserID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    EntryStamp  = models.DateTimeField(db_column='EntryStamp', )  # Field name made lowercase.
    Data = models.TextField(db_column='Data')  # Field name made lowercase.
    guid = models.CharField(db_column='guid', max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'AccountComment'
```

ultimately, want accountComments on the Account Model to use 'AccountID' to do a lookup onto accountComments.accountID and then provide back 'Data'.

I know that I can use

```
def accountComments(self):
    return str(accountComment.objects.get(accountID = self.AccountID).Data)
```

but I want it to work with Django Admin, so I need it to be an integrated part of the model.

Thanks if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Havne't you got the fk the wrong way round? Shouldn't multiple comments be able to relate to one account and not vice versa?

Comment: i'm migrating from 2000 ASP.net where all the comments are one huge text string. So no.

Comment: Ultimately, I see this working if I was able to make another field on Account called 'accountComment' and copied the accountID from all existing fields to 'accountComment' and used the foreign key to reverse with the AccountComment model __str__ returning back the data.. 

I just feel like there has to be a way to define that the foreign key lookup be based on another field on that model.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to do too much with a foreign key. Following a foreign key in Django should return the model instance, not a particular field from the model instance.

The `db_column` should be the column in the `Account` table that stores the id, e.g.

```
accountComments = models.ForeignKey('accountComments',to_field='accountID',db_column='AccountID')
```

Then, to get the `Data` for a particular `account` instance, you would do:

```
account.accountComments.Data
```

Comment: Oooh, I'm so stupid.. Yeah -- there is no reason why I can't define the db_column to be the same thing twice!! I will try this real quick.